# Why isn't a number type initialized to 0?

Tags: javascript, typescript, undefined, nan

I have the following code in a service class:

```
count: number;

increment() {
  this.count++;
  console.log(this.count);
}
```

The log outputs `NaN`.

I'm wondering why it wouldn't initialize count to `0` when I specify a type in the declaration. I've replaced it with `count = 0`, but I'm just curious as to what the logic is behind it.

Comment: Because it is practical for objects to have a null value we can rely on.

An integer is simply in JavaScript an object to begin from, and it is only a number you manipulate and affect a number to it.

Comment: If you are writing typescript, tag `Typescript`, and as I do not see anything related to Angular here, I would also suggest you not include that tag (i.e. it is not relevant as a Typescript class is a Typescript class).

Comment: Well it's not even typescript here but more about JavaScripts and objects in general.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have to do with Angular. JavaScript itself does not ever initialize a value when you define a variable, JavaScript will just allocate that variable as a variable as either an any type.

You're actually writing in TypeScript which of course is a Typed superset of JavaScript and all the

`count: number;`

is doing is allocating the variable `count` and designating it as the type `number`. You the developer have to Initialize the variable yourself because in many cases you don't want the variable to be initialized.

So for example in Vue there is the`@Prop()` decorator which you use to give access to data from a Parent Component to a child.

Example:

```
@Prop(String)
public title?: string
```

So here there is no reason for us to assign this variable a value seeing as it will be passed down from the parent component and rewrite this value.

There are many more cases where you don't want to initialize a variable with a value, do keep in mind that this can lead to undefined values which if you don't handle can be an issue. However if you use something like TSLint in Visual Studio Code or any other extendable editor you'll see when you need to handle that.

```
public exampleFunction() {
  // if you try and use title here it may be undefined
  if (!this.title) {
    return
  }
  // after you check to make sure that title is not undefined you can be sure it's safe to use it
}
```

All in all, having the language not automatically initialize a variable increases the writeability of the language and reduces unnecessary operations.

Answer (score 0):

It's undefined now. That's how javascript works, until you define a variable it's undefined...

In your case, if you want to start count from 0, just set variable value to 0...

Example: `count: number = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

If you are coming from Java, you would expect a `boolean` variable to have a default value of `false`.

Similarly, in JavaScript too, default value *does* exist and that is the primitive value of `undefined`. TypeScript just uses [JavaScript data types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Undefined_type) and doesn't change the behavior.

So, any variable that is defined and is not assigned will get defaulted to `undefined` (and NOT `null`; unlike in Java)

Read on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Undefined